# Is there a way to reopen the ML.NET Model Builder?

Tags: ml.net

After closing the ML.NET Model Builder is it possible to reopen it for the model created?

I can delete the model created and start again, but this is not ideal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not really. AutoML/Model Builder can generate the code and add it to your solution so you can retrain and tweak your model and pipeline, as it sounds like you are trying to do.

The Model Builder is a great place to start, but it's not very helpful for the iterative development process.